# String to ASCII Art Text

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

## The Task

You are to write some ASCII Art Text as seen from [this website for generating ASCII art](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&h=0&f=Alpha&t=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)!

## Rules

Input will only be alphabetical text and spaces, and will be input as a single line. It is also case-insensitive.

You needn't fix if the output text is longer than the terminal width. As long as it would be correct if the terminal window was infinitely stretchable, you'll be fine.

Aside from the standard-loopholes, the only other rule is that you mayn't use built-ins - although if your language *has* a built in for this (which would be *amazing*), if you include it as a side-note in your answer, take a 15% bonus off of your code-golfed solution!

#### Example:

Input:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Output:

```
          _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____            _____                    _____                   _______                   _____                   _______                   _____                    _____                _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                                        _____                    _____                            _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                    _____            _____                    _____                   _______                   _____                   _______                   _____                    _____                _____                    _____                    _____                    _____                                        _____                    _____          
         /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \          /\    \                  /\    \                 /::\    \                 /\    \                 /::\    \                 /\    \                  /\    \              /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                 ______               |\    \                  /\    \                          /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \          /\    \                  /\    \                 /::\    \                 /\    \                 /::\    \                 /\    \                  /\    \              /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                  /\    \                 ______               |\    \                  /\    \         
        /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\____\        /::\____\                /::\____\               /::::\    \               /::\    \               /::::\    \               /::\    \                /::\    \            /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\____\                /::\____\               |::|   |              |:\____\                /::\    \                        /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\    \                /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\____\        /::\____\                /::\____\               /::::\    \               /::\    \               /::::\    \               /::\    \                /::\    \            /::\    \                /::\____\                /::\____\                /::\____\               |::|   |              |:\____\                /::\    \        
       /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /:::/    /                \:::\    \               \:::\    \              /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /::::|   |               /::::|   |              /::::::\    \             /::::\    \             /::::::\    \             /::::\    \              /::::\    \           \:::\    \              /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/    /               |::|   |              |::|   |                \:::\    \                      /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /::::\    \              /:::/    /                \:::\    \               \:::\    \              /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /::::|   |               /::::|   |              /::::::\    \             /::::\    \             /::::::\    \             /::::\    \              /::::\    \           \:::\    \              /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/    /               |::|   |              |::|   |                \:::\    \       
      /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /:::/    /                  \:::\    \               \:::\    \            /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /:::::|   |              /:::::|   |             /::::::::\    \           /::::::\    \           /::::::::\    \           /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \           \:::\    \            /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/   _/___             |::|   |              |::|   |                 \:::\    \                    /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \            /:::/    /                  \:::\    \               \:::\    \            /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /:::::|   |              /:::::|   |             /::::::::\    \           /::::::\    \           /::::::::\    \           /::::::\    \            /::::::\    \           \:::\    \            /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/   _/___             |::|   |              |::|   |                 \:::\    \      
     /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/    /                    \:::\    \               \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /::::::|   |             /::::::|   |            /:::/~~\:::\    \         /:::/\:::\    \         /:::/~~\:::\    \         /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \           \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/   /\    \            |::|   |              |::|   |                  \:::\    \                  /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/    /                    \:::\    \               \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /       /::::::|   |             /::::::|   |            /:::/~~\:::\    \         /:::/\:::\    \         /:::/~~\:::\    \         /:::/\:::\    \          /:::/\:::\    \           \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /               /:::/   /\    \            |::|   |              |::|   |                  \:::\    \     
    /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/____/                      \:::\    \               \:::\    \        /:::/____/               /:::/    /       /:::/|::|   |            /:::/|::|   |           /:::/    \:::\    \       /:::/__\:::\    \       /:::/    \:::\    \       /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \           \:::\    \        /:::/    /               /:::/____/               /:::/   /::\____\           |::|   |              |::|   |                   \:::\    \                /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/  \:::\    \        /:::/____/                      \:::\    \               \:::\    \        /:::/____/               /:::/    /       /:::/|::|   |            /:::/|::|   |           /:::/    \:::\    \       /:::/__\:::\    \       /:::/    \:::\    \       /:::/__\:::\    \        /:::/__\:::\    \           \:::\    \        /:::/    /               /:::/____/               /:::/   /::\____\           |::|   |              |::|   |                   \:::\    \    
   /::::\   \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /::::\    \                      /::::\    \              /::::\    \      /::::\    \              /:::/    /       /:::/ |::|   |           /:::/ |::|   |          /:::/    / \:::\    \     /::::\   \:::\    \     /:::/    / \:::\    \     /::::\   \:::\    \       \:::\   \:::\    \          /::::\    \      /:::/    /                |::|    |               /:::/   /:::/    /           |::|   |              |::|   |                    \:::\    \              /::::\   \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /::::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    \:::\    \      /::::\    \                      /::::\    \              /::::\    \      /::::\    \              /:::/    /       /:::/ |::|   |           /:::/ |::|   |          /:::/    / \:::\    \     /::::\   \:::\    \     /:::/    / \:::\    \     /::::\   \:::\    \       \:::\   \:::\    \          /::::\    \      /:::/    /                |::|    |               /:::/   /:::/    /           |::|   |              |::|   |                    \:::\    \   
  /::::::\   \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /::::::\    \   _____    ____    /::::::\    \    _____   /::::::\    \    /::::::\____\________    /:::/    /       /:::/  |::|___|______    /:::/  |::|   | _____   /:::/____/   \:::\____\   /::::::\   \:::\    \   /:::/____/   \:::\____\   /::::::\   \:::\    \    ___\:::\   \:::\    \        /::::::\    \    /:::/    /      _____      |::|    |     _____    /:::/   /:::/   _/___         |::|   |              |::|___|______               \:::\    \            /::::::\   \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /::::::\   \:::\    \    /:::/    / \:::\    \    /::::::\    \   _____    ____    /::::::\    \    _____   /::::::\    \    /::::::\____\________    /:::/    /       /:::/  |::|___|______    /:::/  |::|   | _____   /:::/____/   \:::\____\   /::::::\   \:::\    \   /:::/____/   \:::\____\   /::::::\   \:::\    \    ___\:::\   \:::\    \        /::::::\    \    /:::/    /      _____      |::|    |     _____    /:::/   /:::/   _/___         |::|   |              |::|___|______               \:::\    \  
 /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/\:::\   \:::\ ___\  /:::/    /   \:::\    \  /:::/    /   \:::\ ___\  /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/    /   \:::\ ___\  /:::/\:::\    \ /\    \  /\   \  /:::/\:::\    \  /\    \ /:::/\:::\    \  /:::/\:::::::::::\    \  /:::/    /       /:::/   |::::::::\    \  /:::/   |::|   |/\    \ |:::|    |     |:::|    | /:::/\:::\   \:::\____\ |:::|    |     |:::|    | /:::/\:::\   \:::\____\  /\   \:::\   \:::\    \      /:::/\:::\    \  /:::/____/      /\    \     |::|    |    /\    \  /:::/___/:::/   /\    \  ______|::|___|___ ____      /::::::::\    \               \:::\    \          /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/\:::\   \:::\ ___\  /:::/    /   \:::\    \  /:::/    /   \:::\ ___\  /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/\:::\   \:::\    \  /:::/    /   \:::\ ___\  /:::/\:::\    \ /\    \  /\   \  /:::/\:::\    \  /\    \ /:::/\:::\    \  /:::/\:::::::::::\    \  /:::/    /       /:::/   |::::::::\    \  /:::/   |::|   |/\    \ |:::|    |     |:::|    | /:::/\:::\   \:::\____\ |:::|    |     |:::|    | /:::/\:::\   \:::\____\  /\   \:::\   \:::\    \      /:::/\:::\    \  /:::/____/      /\    \     |::|    |    /\    \  /:::/___/:::/   /\    \  ______|::|___|___ ____      /::::::::\    \               \:::\    \ 
/:::/  \:::\   \:::\____\/:::/__\:::\   \:::|    |/:::/____/     \:::\____\/:::/____/     \:::|    |/:::/__\:::\   \:::\____\/:::/  \:::\   \:::\____\/:::/____/  ___\:::|    |/:::/  \:::\    /::\____\/::\   \/:::/  \:::\____\/::\    /:::/  \:::\____\/:::/  |:::::::::::\____\/:::/____/       /:::/    |:::::::::\____\/:: /    |::|   /::\____\|:::|____|     |:::|    |/:::/  \:::\   \:::|    ||:::|____|     |:::|____|/:::/  \:::\   \:::|    |/::\   \:::\   \:::\____\    /:::/  \:::\____\|:::|    /      /::\____\    |::|    |   /::\____\|:::|   /:::/   /::\____\|:::::::::::::::::|    |    /::::::::::\____\_______________\:::\____\        /:::/  \:::\   \:::\____\/:::/__\:::\   \:::|    |/:::/____/     \:::\____\/:::/____/     \:::|    |/:::/__\:::\   \:::\____\/:::/  \:::\   \:::\____\/:::/____/  ___\:::|    |/:::/  \:::\    /::\____\/::\   \/:::/  \:::\____\/::\    /:::/  \:::\____\/:::/  |:::::::::::\____\/:::/____/       /:::/    |:::::::::\____\/:: /    |::|   /::\____\|:::|____|     |:::|    |/:::/  \:::\   \:::|    ||:::|____|     |:::|____|/:::/  \:::\   \:::|    |/::\   \:::\   \:::\____\    /:::/  \:::\____\|:::|    /      /::\____\    |::|    |   /::\____\|:::|   /:::/   /::\____\|:::::::::::::::::|    |    /::::::::::\____\_______________\:::\____\
\::/    \:::\  /:::/    /\:::\   \:::\  /:::|____|\:::\    \      \::/    /\:::\    \     /:::|____|\:::\   \:::\   \::/    /\::/    \:::\   \::/    /\:::\    \ /\  /:::|____|\::/    \:::\  /:::/    /\:::\  /:::/    \::/    /\:::\  /:::/    \::/    /\::/   |::|~~~|~~~~~     \:::\    \       \::/    / ~~~~~/:::/    /\::/    /|::|  /:::/    / \:::\    \   /:::/    / \::/    \:::\  /:::|____| \:::\   _\___/:::/    / \::/   |::::\  /:::|____|\:::\   \:::\   \::/    /   /:::/    \::/    /|:::|____\     /:::/    /    |::|    |  /:::/    /|:::|__/:::/   /:::/    /|:::::::::::::::::|____|   /:::/~~~~/~~      \::::::::::::::::::/    /        \::/    \:::\  /:::/    /\:::\   \:::\  /:::|____|\:::\    \      \::/    /\:::\    \     /:::|____|\:::\   \:::\   \::/    /\::/    \:::\   \::/    /\:::\    \ /\  /:::|____|\::/    \:::\  /:::/    /\:::\  /:::/    \::/    /\:::\  /:::/    \::/    /\::/   |::|~~~|~~~~~     \:::\    \       \::/    / ~~~~~/:::/    /\::/    /|::|  /:::/    / \:::\    \   /:::/    / \::/    \:::\  /:::|____| \:::\   _\___/:::/    / \::/   |::::\  /:::|____|\:::\   \:::\   \::/    /   /:::/    \::/    /|:::|____\     /:::/    /    |::|    |  /:::/    /|:::|__/:::/   /:::/    /|:::::::::::::::::|____|   /:::/~~~~/~~      \::::::::::::::::::/    /
 \/____/ \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\    \      \/____/  \:::\    \   /:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\   \/____/  \/____/ \:::\   \/____/  \:::\    /::\ \::/    /  \/____/ \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\/:::/    / \/____/  \:::\/:::/    / \/____/  \/____|::|   |           \:::\    \       \/____/      /:::/    /  \/____/ |::| /:::/    /   \:::\    \ /:::/    /   \/_____/\:::\/:::/    /   \:::\ |::| /:::/    /   \/____|:::::\/:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\   \/____/   /:::/    / \/____/  \:::\    \   /:::/    /     |::|    | /:::/    /  \:::\/:::/   /:::/    /  ~~~~~~|::|~~~|~~~        /:::/    /          \::::::::::::::::/____/          \/____/ \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\    \      \/____/  \:::\    \   /:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\   \/____/  \/____/ \:::\   \/____/  \:::\    /::\ \::/    /  \/____/ \:::\/:::/    /  \:::\/:::/    / \/____/  \:::\/:::/    / \/____/  \/____|::|   |           \:::\    \       \/____/      /:::/    /  \/____/ |::| /:::/    /   \:::\    \ /:::/    /   \/_____/\:::\/:::/    /   \:::\ |::| /:::/    /   \/____|:::::\/:::/    /  \:::\   \:::\   \/____/   /:::/    / \/____/  \:::\    \   /:::/    /     |::|    | /:::/    /  \:::\/:::/   /:::/    /  ~~~~~~|::|~~~|~~~        /:::/    /          \::::::::::::::::/____/ 
          \::::::/    /    \:::\   \::::::/    /    \:::\    \               \:::\    \ /:::/    /    \:::\   \:::\    \               \:::\    \       \:::\   \:::\ \/____/            \::::::/    /    \::::::/    /            \::::::/    /                 |::|   |            \:::\    \                  /:::/    /           |::|/:::/    /     \:::\    /:::/    /             \::::::/    /     \:::\|::|/:::/    /          |:::::::::/    /    \:::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    /            \:::\    \ /:::/    /      |::|____|/:::/    /    \::::::/   /:::/    /         |::|   |          /:::/    /            \:::\~~~~\~~~~~~                         \::::::/    /    \:::\   \::::::/    /    \:::\    \               \:::\    \ /:::/    /    \:::\   \:::\    \               \:::\    \       \:::\   \:::\ \/____/            \::::::/    /    \::::::/    /            \::::::/    /                 |::|   |            \:::\    \                  /:::/    /           |::|/:::/    /     \:::\    /:::/    /             \::::::/    /     \:::\|::|/:::/    /          |:::::::::/    /    \:::\   \:::\    \      /:::/    /            \:::\    \ /:::/    /      |::|____|/:::/    /    \::::::/   /:::/    /         |::|   |          /:::/    /            \:::\~~~~\~~~~~~       
           \::::/    /      \:::\   \::::/    /      \:::\    \               \:::\    /:::/    /      \:::\   \:::\____\               \:::\____\       \:::\   \:::\____\               \::::/    /      \::::/____/              \::::/    /                  |::|   |             \:::\    \                /:::/    /            |::::::/    /       \:::\__/:::/    /               \::::/    /       \::::::::::/    /           |::|\::::/    /      \:::\   \:::\____\    /:::/    /              \:::\    /:::/    /       |:::::::::::/    /      \::::/___/:::/    /          |::|   |         /:::/    /              \:::\    \                               \::::/    /      \:::\   \::::/    /      \:::\    \               \:::\    /:::/    /      \:::\   \:::\____\               \:::\____\       \:::\   \:::\____\               \::::/    /      \::::/____/              \::::/    /                  |::|   |             \:::\    \                /:::/    /            |::::::/    /       \:::\__/:::/    /               \::::/    /       \::::::::::/    /           |::|\::::/    /      \:::\   \:::\____\    /:::/    /              \:::\    /:::/    /       |:::::::::::/    /      \::::/___/:::/    /          |::|   |         /:::/    /              \:::\    \            
           /:::/    /        \:::\  /:::/    /        \:::\    \               \:::\  /:::/    /        \:::\   \::/    /                \::/    /        \:::\  /:::/    /               /:::/    /        \:::\    \               \::/    /                   |::|   |              \:::\    \              /:::/    /             |:::::/    /         \::::::::/    /                 \::/____/         \::::::::/    /            |::| \::/____/        \:::\  /:::/    /    \::/    /                \:::\__/:::/    /        \::::::::::/____/        \:::\__/:::/    /           |::|   |         \::/    /                \:::\    \                              /:::/    /        \:::\  /:::/    /        \:::\    \               \:::\  /:::/    /        \:::\   \::/    /                \::/    /        \:::\  /:::/    /               /:::/    /        \:::\    \               \::/    /                   |::|   |              \:::\    \              /:::/    /             |:::::/    /         \::::::::/    /                 \::/____/         \::::::::/    /            |::| \::/____/        \:::\  /:::/    /    \::/    /                \:::\__/:::/    /        \::::::::::/____/        \:::\__/:::/    /           |::|   |         \::/    /                \:::\    \           
          /:::/    /          \:::\/:::/    /          \:::\    \               \:::\/:::/    /          \:::\   \/____/                  \/____/          \:::\/:::/    /               /:::/    /          \:::\    \               \/____/                    |::|   |               \:::\    \            /:::/    /              |::::/    /           \::::::/    /                   ~~                \::::::/    /             |::|  ~|               \:::\/:::/    /      \/____/                  \::::::::/    /          ~~~~~~~~~~               \::::::::/    /            |::|   |          \/____/                  \:::\    \                            /:::/    /          \:::\/:::/    /          \:::\    \               \:::\/:::/    /          \:::\   \/____/                  \/____/          \:::\/:::/    /               /:::/    /          \:::\    \               \/____/                    |::|   |               \:::\    \            /:::/    /              |::::/    /           \::::::/    /                   ~~                \::::::/    /             |::|  ~|               \:::\/:::/    /      \/____/                  \::::::::/    /          ~~~~~~~~~~               \::::::::/    /            |::|   |          \/____/                  \:::\    \          
         /:::/    /            \::::::/    /            \:::\    \               \::::::/    /            \:::\    \                                        \::::::/    /               /:::/    /            \:::\    \                                         |::|   |                \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /             \::::/    /                                       \::::/____/              |::|   |                \::::::/    /                                 \::::::/    /                                     \::::::/    /             |::|   |                                    \:::\    \                          /:::/    /            \::::::/    /            \:::\    \               \::::::/    /            \:::\    \                                        \::::::/    /               /:::/    /            \:::\    \                                         |::|   |                \:::\    \          /:::/    /               /:::/    /             \::::/    /                                       \::::/____/              |::|   |                \::::::/    /                                 \::::::/    /                                     \::::::/    /             |::|   |                                    \:::\    \         
        /:::/    /              \::::/    /              \:::\____\               \::::/    /              \:::\____\                                        \::::/    /               /:::/    /              \:::\____\                                        \::|   |                 \:::\____\        /:::/    /               /:::/    /               \::/____/                                         |::|    |               \::|   |                 \::::/    /                                   \::::/    /                                       \::::/    /              |::|   |                                     \:::\____\                        /:::/    /              \::::/    /              \:::\____\               \::::/    /              \:::\____\                                        \::::/    /               /:::/    /              \:::\____\                                        \::|   |                 \:::\____\        /:::/    /               /:::/    /               \::/____/                                         |::|    |               \::|   |                 \::::/    /                                   \::::/    /                                       \::::/    /              |::|   |                                     \:::\____\        
        \::/    /                \::/____/                \::/    /                \::/____/                \::/    /                                         \::/____/                \::/    /                \::/    /                                         \:|   |                  \::/    /        \::/    /                \::/    /                 ~~                                               |::|____|                \:|   |                  \::/    /                                     \::/____/                                         \::/____/               |::|___|                                      \::/    /                        \::/    /                \::/____/                \::/    /                \::/____/                \::/    /                                         \::/____/                \::/    /                \::/    /                                         \:|   |                  \::/    /        \::/    /                \::/    /                 ~~                                               |::|____|                \:|   |                  \::/    /                                     \::/____/                                         \::/____/               |::|___|                                      \::/    /        
         \/____/                  ~~                       \/____/                  ~~                       \/____/                                                                    \/____/                  \/____/                                           \|___|                   \/____/          \/____/                  \/____/                                                                    ~~                       \|___|                   \/____/                                       ~~                                                ~~                      ~~                                            \/____/                          \/____/                  ~~                       \/____/                  ~~                       \/____/                                                                    \/____/                  \/____/                                           \|___|                   \/____/          \/____/                  \/____/                                                                    ~~                       \|___|                   \/____/                                       ~~                                                ~~                      ~~                                            \/____/
```

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the fewest amount of bytes wins!

Comment: You should probably add a space in the input to show what they should look like.

Comment: Just for you @VoteToClose, I wiil find a way to do this in Minecraft.

Comment: @GamrCorps I'm fairly certain it's impossible, but yuuus. :D I will bounty largely for that.

Comment: @VoteToClose A 3D calculator was made in minecraft. This should be possible :P

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ But strings/multilines _suuuck_.

Comment: Good job btw on 1.8K rep _exactly_

Comment: Please clarify 15% bonus rule: 1) what do you count in as "built-ins"? it's very vague: is function to do decompression a builtin? is a function to upper/lower case the string / letter a builtin? a function to determine ASCII code of a character? hex / some other base conversion? 2) how exactly applying 15% bonus works — it's very ambiguous now — how many times does it gets applied (once for every builtin not used but could be?), what do you want to see in a mentioned sidenote, etc?

Comment: @GreyCat If your language had a builtin that did something like `input.toASCIIArtForm("Alpha")` (Alpha is the name of the "font" used here), where the conversion is a one-step method call, then that would be a built in. It is a one-time bonus.

Comment: This suspiciously looks like figlet / "toilet" (http://www.figlet.org) ...

Answer (score 27):

## Minecraft, 22313 (50% hand-written code) bytes

Why did I ever promise to do this.... Well, it works, but I took a few liberties:

- Letters are followed by newlines
- There is no lowercase input (as uppercase and lowercase are the same)
- Letters look weird as Minecraft does not have monospaced font (it looks better with 'Force Unicode Font' in language settings)

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Screenshot of output:
[image]

Download the world [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qimtts0i62icuwc/String_to_ASCII_Art.zip). Note that the input keyboard is very precise on the clicking. Click a little to the right of each letter to avoid this confusion.

#### Explanation

1. Input Keyboard pops up, takes input until 'Enter' "key" is pressed.
2. Teleports the "Controller" `ArmorStand` backwards one block until it reaches end of string.
3. While it is teleporting, the `ArmorStand` checks what character that the `ArmorStand` it is standing on represents, and activates that command block (which outputs the fancy letter).
4. Once the Controller reaches the starting position, it resets the program and kills the `ArmorStand`s.

Comment: How many bytes is this?

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος I am counting right now, but I figured I would post it until I have the count.

Comment: Counting method:
1 for command block
2 for 1.8 command block
{command length} for commands themselves

Comment: BTW - you just earned _400 rep_ on an answer. xD

Comment: @VoteToClose lol, its amazing.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>14394</s> <s>6381</s> 3360 bytes

```js
f=s=>[...s.toUpperCase(b="e_5yyyyyyyyyyyh_5yx_7x_5x_7x_5yr_5yyyR0_5ynd/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTfbTv/bTu/DTu/bTu/DTu/bTv/bTk/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTu_6 15|bTv/bTdncDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDBsDTsDTsDBsDBcDBsDBp4bTp2bTp4bTp2bTsDTiDTsDBsDBsDB 15|FOm:bBsDTnZJTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo3/StHTq3bTo3/Sp3/SZ:4|Op4|Oo6bTj/JTj/LTj/JTo4bTgbHTo3/Sp3/Sp3/S 15|FOmFOtHTnWLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiGSwHTq3bTiGSp3/SZ:5|Oo5|Oj/:8bTg/LTg/:8bTg/LTiLTgbHTiGSp3/Sp3/ 3_/_3j|FOmFOubHTnU/GbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGS 20bHTq3bTfGSp3/SZ:6|Oj/:6|OiG~2bHTd/GbHTd/G~2bHTd/GbHTfGbHTgbHTfGSp3/Sp3/PbTh|FOmFOwHTnSG_2bHTcG_2bHTcGMHTcGMHTcG_2bHTcG_2bHTcGMHTcGC 22bHTq3bTcGCp3/SZG|FOiG|FOg/GTHTZG_2bHTZGTHTZG_2bHTcG_2bHTgbHTcGSp3/Cp3/PDBg|FOmFOxbHTnPJQHTWJQHTWGTHTWGTHTWJQHTWJQHTWGTHTWJT 22/JTo4bTWJTo3/SZG |FOg/G |FOfGS bHTU/JQHTU/GS bHTU/JQHTYbHQHTfJTWGSr|FR|p3/PGSg|FOmFO 20bHTnNLQHTSLQHTSGS bHTSGS bHTSLQHTSLQHTSGS bHTSLT 3_5RASLTR_5PLTSLB_8SGSZG 2|F_3|_6SG 2|FO _5PGCQHBPLQHTPGCQHBPLQHTR_3bHQHTcLTSGSV_5V|FR|U_5SGPG 3_/_3d|FOmF_3|_6q3bTn /GbHQHTNGbHQH _3bNGSQHTNGSQH _3bNGbHQHTNGbHQHTNGSQH _3bNGbHT /bTNbQNGbHTNbT /GbHTNGb:11bTNGSZGO:8bTNGOFO/bT |:3|R|U|:3|R| /GbHQHB |:3|R|U|:3|R| /GbHQHBNbQHQHTWGbHTNGCWbTU|FR|SbTNG_3/GPbT 2_6|F_3|_3 AW:8bTq3bTn/GMHQHB/G_2bHQ:3|R|/GCUbHB/GCUb:3|R|/G_2bHQHB/GMHQHB/GC 2_3b:3|R|/GMHSDB/DQ/GMHB/DSGMHB/G 2|:11bB/GCZGR|:9bB/:2 /R|FPDB|:3|A|U|:3|R|/GMHQ:3|R|2:3|A|U|:3|A|/GMHQ:3|R|/DQHQHBSGMHB|:3|SWDBR|FR|PDB|:3|PGPDB|:17|R|S:10bB_15bHBnbETHNGSbHQHN:3|A|bHTXESbHTU/:3|A|bHQHQESbETHQESbHT /bN:3|A|bETHNGSbHNGTESbHNGTESbEOF~3|~5UbHTYbES ~5/GSbES|FNGS bHTPGS bETHN:3|A| bH 3_b_3/GS bEOJN:3|A|bHQHQESPGTES|:3|BU/GSR|FR|NGS|:3|_2/GPGS|:17|A|PG~4/~2X:18/Sn b/C bH/GSMHQH/GSMHTX/CMHTPGSMHQHQ/CM/C bHQ/CMHSD bESM/C bH/GSMH/GS b/CMH/GS b/CM/A|FOgbHTYb/CWGSM/C |F /GSQHT /GSQ/_5/bH/GSQH |F /GSQ/A|:5b/GSMHQHQ/CPGS b/CMHTPGSU|FR| /GSMH/GPGS 2~6|F~3|~3cGSeb:16/CnebKSTHQKSTHTq3bT /GSTHQHTq3bTYbHQH b/ChbKSTKShbKSu|FOhbHTv/GSg|F/GSUbHSGSjbKSUbH|F/GSe|:9/STHQHTWGShbHT /GSV|FA|/GSTKPGSd|FOfGShbH~4b~6ngbISXHQISXHTq3bSGSXHQHBq3bBYbHQHBq4/SXICl4/Sv|FOjbHTsGSh|KSYbH_2/GSq4/SYb:10/Sg|FbISXHQHBSGSl3bSGSY|:11/SXI_3/GSe|FOd/GSl3bTng/GSabHNGSabHTq3bNGSabHQEStESabHNGSp3/SabHTq2/Sx|FOl3bTo3/Sj|:5/Sdb:8/SubECdb:8/Sh|F bECabHNGSTEStH_2/GSab:10/CabH_2/GSg|FOdbEStHTnfGSebH/GSebHTq3b/GSebHQ/Cw/CebH/GSp3/SebHT 15b/C 20|FOq3bTiGSmISgbKSx~2tKSj|F 2~|q3b/GSX/Cw:8/Se~10q8/Sh|FOeb/CwHTend/GShbKShbHTq6/ShbHTR0bKSp3/ShbHTR1|FOtHTfGSp3/SjbIS 39bICmFOtKS 33bKS 37bKSj|FO 36bHTncGSl4/Sl3bBq4/Sl3bBR0bISp3/Sl3bBR0bFOubHBcGSp3/Sq2/CR1|FR|q2|OubIS 35bIS 39bISmFO 37bHBnabEStECtEStECtESR1bECtEStESR1b:|OwESabEStESu~2R7|FA|t:|OwES 37bECR1bEC 15|F_3| 38bESndb/Cv~2 23b/Cv~2 23b/CV8b/Cw/CR3b|_3|xb/Ceb/Cw/CV8~2 23b|_3|xb/C 39~2R8~2 22~2R4b/C",["_4","_4b","_4/",":2b",":2/",":2|",":3/",":3b",":4/",":4b",":6/",":6b"," 2b"," 2/"," 3|"," 3/"," 3b"," 4"," 4/"," 4b"," 5"," 6"," 6/"," 6b"," 7"," 7/"," 8"," 8/"," 9"," 10"," 10/"," 11"," 12"," 12/"," 13"," 14"," 14b:"," 14|"," 14/:"," 15/:"," 15b:"," 16"," 16/"," 16b"," 17"," 18"," 18b"," 19"," 20_5","\\"].map((l,i)=>b=b.replace(new RegExp([..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZacdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyb"][i],"g"),l)),a="",b.match(/\D|\d+/g).map(x=>a+=+x?l.repeat(x-1):l=x),a=a.split`n`,o=a.map(_=>""))].map(c=>a.map((d,i)=>o[i]+=c<"A"?"        ":d.slice((g=n=>(c.charCodeAt()+n-65)*25-(c>"L")*8-(c>"T")*4-(c>"Y")*4)(0),g(1))))&&o.join`
`
```

### Explanation

ASCII art string is compressed using the format `<character><number_of_times_to_repeat>`. After this another stage of compression is added where numerous common combinations (eg. `20_5`) are replaced by single characters. Special characters `n` represents a new line and `b` represents a backslash.

I could probably improve the compression algorithm a bit but I think I'll leave it like this for now.

```js
f=s=>
  [...s.toUpperCase(              // use upper-case letter codes

    // magical decompression magic
    b="e_5yyyyyyyyyyyh_5yx_7x_5x_7x_5yr_5yyyR0_5ynd/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTfbTv/bTu/DTu/bTu/DTu/bTv/bTk/bTv/bTv/bTv/bTu_6 15|bTv/bTdncDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDTsDBsDTsDTsDBsDBcDBsDBp4bTp2bTp4bTp2bTsDTiDTsDBsDBsDB 15|FOm:bBsDTnZJTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo4bTo3/StHTq3bTo3/Sp3/SZ:4|Op4|Oo6bTj/JTj/LTj/JTo4bTgbHTo3/Sp3/Sp3/S 15|FOmFOtHTnWLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiLTiGSwHTq3bTiGSp3/SZ:5|Oo5|Oj/:8bTg/LTg/:8bTg/LTiLTgbHTiGSp3/Sp3/ 3_/_3j|FOmFOubHTnU/GbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGbHTfGS 20bHTq3bTfGSp3/SZ:6|Oj/:6|OiG~2bHTd/GbHTd/G~2bHTd/GbHTfGbHTgbHTfGSp3/Sp3/PbTh|FOmFOwHTnSG_2bHTcG_2bHTcGMHTcGMHTcG_2bHTcG_2bHTcGMHTcGC 22bHTq3bTcGCp3/SZG|FOiG|FOg/GTHTZG_2bHTZGTHTZG_2bHTcG_2bHTgbHTcGSp3/Cp3/PDBg|FOmFOxbHTnPJQHTWJQHTWGTHTWGTHTWJQHTWJQHTWGTHTWJT 22/JTo4bTWJTo3/SZG |FOg/G |FOfGS bHTU/JQHTU/GS bHTU/JQHTYbHQHTfJTWGSr|FR|p3/PGSg|FOmFO 20bHTnNLQHTSLQHTSGS bHTSGS bHTSLQHTSLQHTSGS bHTSLT 3_5RASLTR_5PLTSLB_8SGSZG 2|F_3|_6SG 2|FO _5PGCQHBPLQHTPGCQHBPLQHTR_3bHQHTcLTSGSV_5V|FR|U_5SGPG 3_/_3d|FOmF_3|_6q3bTn /GbHQHTNGbHQH _3bNGSQHTNGSQH _3bNGbHQHTNGbHQHTNGSQH _3bNGbHT /bTNbQNGbHTNbT /GbHTNGb:11bTNGSZGO:8bTNGOFO/bT |:3|R|U|:3|R| /GbHQHB |:3|R|U|:3|R| /GbHQHBNbQHQHTWGbHTNGCWbTU|FR|SbTNG_3/GPbT 2_6|F_3|_3 AW:8bTq3bTn/GMHQHB/G_2bHQ:3|R|/GCUbHB/GCUb:3|R|/G_2bHQHB/GMHQHB/GC 2_3b:3|R|/GMHSDB/DQ/GMHB/DSGMHB/G 2|:11bB/GCZGR|:9bB/:2 /R|FPDB|:3|A|U|:3|R|/GMHQ:3|R|2:3|A|U|:3|A|/GMHQ:3|R|/DQHQHBSGMHB|:3|SWDBR|FR|PDB|:3|PGPDB|:17|R|S:10bB_15bHBnbETHNGSbHQHN:3|A|bHTXESbHTU/:3|A|bHQHQESbETHQESbHT /bN:3|A|bETHNGSbHNGTESbHNGTESbEOF~3|~5UbHTYbES ~5/GSbES|FNGS bHTPGS bETHN:3|A| bH 3_b_3/GS bEOJN:3|A|bHQHQESPGTES|:3|BU/GSR|FR|NGS|:3|_2/GPGS|:17|A|PG~4/~2X:18/Sn b/C bH/GSMHQH/GSMHTX/CMHTPGSMHQHQ/CM/C bHQ/CMHSD bESM/C bH/GSMH/GS b/CMH/GS b/CM/A|FOgbHTYb/CWGSM/C |F /GSQHT /GSQ/_5/bH/GSQH |F /GSQ/A|:5b/GSMHQHQ/CPGS b/CMHTPGSU|FR| /GSMH/GPGS 2~6|F~3|~3cGSeb:16/CnebKSTHQKSTHTq3bT /GSTHQHTq3bTYbHQH b/ChbKSTKShbKSu|FOhbHTv/GSg|F/GSUbHSGSjbKSUbH|F/GSe|:9/STHQHTWGShbHT /GSV|FA|/GSTKPGSd|FOfGShbH~4b~6ngbISXHQISXHTq3bSGSXHQHBq3bBYbHQHBq4/SXICl4/Sv|FOjbHTsGSh|KSYbH_2/GSq4/SYb:10/Sg|FbISXHQHBSGSl3bSGSY|:11/SXI_3/GSe|FOd/GSl3bTng/GSabHNGSabHTq3bNGSabHQEStESabHNGSp3/SabHTq2/Sx|FOl3bTo3/Sj|:5/Sdb:8/SubECdb:8/Sh|F bECabHNGSTEStH_2/GSab:10/CabH_2/GSg|FOdbEStHTnfGSebH/GSebHTq3b/GSebHQ/Cw/CebH/GSp3/SebHT 15b/C 20|FOq3bTiGSmISgbKSx~2tKSj|F 2~|q3b/GSX/Cw:8/Se~10q8/Sh|FOeb/CwHTend/GShbKShbHTq6/ShbHTR0bKSp3/ShbHTR1|FOtHTfGSp3/SjbIS 39bICmFOtKS 33bKS 37bKSj|FO 36bHTncGSl4/Sl3bBq4/Sl3bBR0bISp3/Sl3bBR0bFOubHBcGSp3/Sq2/CR1|FR|q2|OubIS 35bIS 39bISmFO 37bHBnabEStECtEStECtESR1bECtEStESR1b:|OwESabEStESu~2R7|FA|t:|OwES 37bECR1bEC 15|F_3| 38bESndb/Cv~2 23b/Cv~2 23b/CV8b/Cw/CR3b|_3|xb/Ceb/Cw/CV8~2 23b|_3|xb/C 39~2R8~2 22~2R4b/C",
    ["_4","_4b","_4/",":2b",":2/",":2|",":3/",":3b",":4/",":4b",":6/",":6b"," 2b"," 2/"," 3|"," 3/"," 3b"," 4"," 4/"," 4b"," 5"," 6"," 6/"," 6b"," 7"," 7/"," 8"," 8/"," 9"," 10"," 10/"," 11"," 12"," 12/"," 13"," 14"," 14b:"," 14|"," 14/:"," 15/:"," 15b:"," 16"," 16/"," 16b"," 17"," 18"," 18b"," 19"," 20_5","\\"]
      .map((l,i)=>b=b.replace(new RegExp([..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZacdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyb"][i],"g"),l)),
    
    // decompression stage 2
    a="",                         // a = array of each line of the ASCII art letters
    b.match(/\D|\d+/g)            // get an array of characters and numbers
      .map(x=>
        a+=+x                     // if the current element is a number
          ?l.repeat(x-1)          // repeat the previous character x times
          :l=x                    // else set l to the new character
                                  // add it to a in case there is no number after it
      ),
    
    a=a.split`n`,                 // split a into an array of lines
    o=a.map(_=>"")                // o = array containing each line of the output
  )].map(c=>
    a.map((d,i)=>                 // loop through each line of the current letter
      o[i]+=                      // add the letter's substring for the current line
        c<"A"?"        ":         // space = 8 spaces
        d.slice(
          (g=n=>
            (c.charCodeAt()+n-65) // get the letter index
              *25                 // each ASCII art letter is 25 characters wide
              -(c>"L")*8          // except L is 17
              -(c>"T")*4          // T is 21
              -(c>"Y")*4          // Y is 21
          )(0),g(1))
    )
  )
  &&o.join`
`
```

```html
Letters to Test: <input type="text" oninput="output.innerHTML=f(this.value)" /><pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Fun fact: I had to golf the explanation a bit because the answer was originally over 30000 characters. I never thought I'd hit that limit on a code golf answer!

Comment: Some of these letters (for example, test the string 'zyx') don't seem to be displaying properly.  Is this a problem with the snippet, or the code itself?

Comment: @KevinW. Oops. I know why. It's because I removed the trailing whitespace after the Z character when I was experimenting. I'll fix it when I have the time to look at it. (I'll need to recompress it D: )

Answer (score 9):

## PHP, 1898 <s>1905</s> <s>1922</s> bytes

Yeah, PHP beats all, at least currently. :)

```php
$r=[L=>8,T=>4,V=>4,X=>1,Y=>4];for(;$c=strtoupper($argv[1][$z++]);)foreach(explode("
",gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')))as$k=>$v)$o[$k].=' '==$c?'        ':substr($v,(ord($c)-65)*25,25-$r[$c]);echo implode("
",$o);
```

Works from command line:

```
$ php asciistuff.php HelLo
$ php asciistuff.php "H E L L O"
```

It handles upper- and lowercase characters as well as whitespaces.

**Golfed version without the long string**

```php
$r=[L=>8,T=>4,V=>4,X=>1,Y=>4];for(;$c=strtoupper($argv[1][$z++]);)foreach(explode("
",gzuncompress(base64_decode('encoded alphabet')))as$k=>$v)$o[$k].=' '==$c?'        ':substr($v,(ord($c)-65)*25,25-$r[$c]);echo implode("
",$o);
```

**Ungolfed**

```php
// store difference of shorter letters to default value (25)
$r=[L=>8,T=>4,V=>4,X=>1,Y=>4];

// loop through each character in the input
for(;$c = strtoupper($argv[1][$z++]);)
    // the whole alphabet is compressed and stored in a base64 encoded string
    // it's then stored line by line in an array
    // for each character we loop through every line of the alphabet
    foreach(explode("\n",gzuncompress(base64_decode('encoded alphabet'))) as $k => $v)
        // if a white space is given, 8 whitespaces are added to each line of the output
        // otherwise the letter sequence, dependent on letter length, is extracted from the current line
        $o[$k] .= ' ' == $c ? '        ' : substr($v, (ord($c) - 65) * 25, 25 - $r[$c]);
// finally print the result
echo implode("\n",$o);
```

---

**Edits**

- *Saved* **17 bytes** by refactoring the loops and declaring the lines of the alphabet inline.
- *Saved* **7 bytes** by replacing `foreach()` with `implode()` and by replacing `"\n"` with real line breaks.

Comment: When I run the literal `php asciistuff.php HelLo` command in the terminal, it just echoes the contents of asciistuff.php. I straight copied and pasted the contents of the first code block. What am I doing wrong? Running stock PHP (5.5.27) on Mac OS 10.10.5.

Comment: @benpop You have to add `<?php ` in the beginning of the file. I've not added it into the byte count. If you're interested, here's a discussion about it: [Is the PHP opening tag mandatory in byte count?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7098/41859).

Comment: `ucfirst` instead `strtoupper`  `bzcompress ` saves 50 Bytes for the base64 string

Answer (score 5):

## Matlab (Java), <s>28125</s> <s>28119</s> 6810 bytes

Could perhaps still be golfed somewhat more. Now I am using a string compression via Java, stolen from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8899-rapid-lossless-data-compression-of-numerical-or-string-variables/content/dzip.m)

The core is the nice thing that in Matlab you can also get 2d (or if you need 3d etc) slices from matrices, and also *stick* them together again. This saves a lot of work! This is done for every character of the input.

```
Z=uint8([120;156;237;155;193;145;219;60;12;133;51;255;164;16;116;160;91;14;62;165;16;206;160;145;29;55;145;38;83;70;86;36;1;226;1;240;102;253;175;44;75;14;117;241;228;139;150;164;200;199;7;144;18;191;255;247;173;94;63;126;214;159;223;191;126;146;94;75;161;120;45;151;75;196;239;240;178;164;144;211;59;57;131;142;174;112;173;138;3;92;241;226;255;188;92;180;97;181;221;189;118;197;181;221;92;255;249;94;98;199;210;26;185;171;254;246;191;28;119;213;223;126;39;147;195;181;221;181;141;80;102;109;119;33;40;179;54;131;12;182;208;98;3;7;6;40;216;193;134;217;195;138;57;192;21;115;132;239;152;19;40;181;249;235;62;149;4;172;35;234;161;29;209;1;205;136;154;50;205;88;185;50;7;134;50;229;215;149;185;254;94;83;149;92;83;149;80;166;18;166;76;37;157;58;149;212;27;201;149;217;111;36;218;72;37;111;111;8;187;28;162;32;74;163;65;37;43;77;84;66;156;9;162;213;230;175;231;171;100;161;68;37;11;142;21;204;94;167;146;241;20;13;179;254;175;237;125;169;185;222;222;231;40;187;154;219;28;101;87;179;12;10;212;76;58;40;197;99;70;47;17;236;84;130;61;6;42;241;56;120;181;180;51;226;132;74;59;3;62;151;151;108;171;146;107;80;9;122;73;87;73;244;146;209;68;172;89;155;56;189;196;195;243;70;156;152;151;160;151;24;28;243;146;18;189;164;151;233;189;164;104;6;3;238;240;94;102;226;37;235;125;209;75;236;12;183;158;103;230;189;120;137;155;247;226;37;197;171;228;32;94;114;156;236;213;214;142;56;168;164;209;160;146;70;51;28;85;34;20;85;82;47;175;18;138;216;140;210;63;161;146;227;71;28;130;136;179;244;232;48;84;178;180;167;11;17;135;211;236;149;211;236;149;69;37;46;226;148;214;199;62;226;20;179;30;49;17;199;134;12;85;9;67;200;144;136;195;65;37;213;220;130;74;56;19;196;254;17;231;56;94;242;241;74;216;42;79;87;194;86;121;186;18;94;137;142;255;69;102;51;147;85;158;172;132;25;114;29;89;9;179;203;117;250;74;120;113;189;22;30;198;67;142;121;73;173;33;174;132;213;51;220;112;100;201;10;229;201;202;195;188;132;189;59;244;54;100;216;251;189;210;12;151;220;167;10;248;148;180;19;212;178;12;117;12;181;176;83;7;228;37;214;167;70;94;98;124;202;230;37;195;167;66;94;178;168;147;155;24;210;212;242;111;175;113;30;165;18;166;212;167;10;250;20;168;68;158;26;84;34;142;132;42;81;154;236;124;145;83;137;116;155;83;137;105;167;85;137;182;147;64;37;17;211;231;241;249;85;178;119;196;121;235;151;91;227;200;229;34;206;192;18;113;120;20;177;134;246;30;113;120;93;22;247;107;68;156;140;46;37;161;75;29;76;83;174;244;182;189;119;189;90;111;123;218;203;202;105;73;41;149;148;38;227;126;23;165;146;82;202;228;240;122;217;107;129;248;110;215;14;38;190;235;28;197;248;46;115;212;197;247;98;168;153;38;18;113;220;156;148;136;227;109;1;254;253;252;185;57;92;214;87;244;81;2;165;217;224;165;207;17;109;55;143;169;122;181;173;41;150;142;108;176;205;177;74;229;78;81;115;157;67;218;110;75;49;27;236;20;179;65;41;55;121;24;206;224;139;100;131;183;84;66;71;80;73;187;188;74;244;2;149;40;52;42;209;33;181;42;193;118;91;26;85;226;155;88;70;147;206;191;102;72;151;155;27;24;120;237;242;96;224;62;163;212;25;29;13;220;189;179;48;99;53;48;119;103;224;250;20;250;175;254;219;12;92;105;182;225;141;53;171;47;218;154;135;226;77;205;70;241;26;81;234;19;143;24;35;24;245;0;139;213;49;118;144;12;98;162;201;55;54;188;61;108;17;37;192;174;226;68;36;25;188;181;253;112;128;136;115;123;255;129;253;159;183;180;63;212;254;232;189;204;171;82;43;147;158;164;153;93;42;219;65;32;147;184;105;233;58;200;200;196;62;244;144;9;116;80;201;109;227;113;239;69;78;232;37;45;50;172;13;55;94;194;18;70;174;224;37;134;14;47;97;83;194;168;130;135;184;77;205;172;77;140;94;162;20;188;164;219;157;96;49;152;214;209;219;121;201;158;34;57;180;151;124;97;101;169;94;34;89;75;234;37;217;219;51;31;213;196;75;226;87;61;178;178;84;252;186;94;242;144;93;170;37;248;253;40;51;154;73;192;198;160;156;153;248;17;117;17;199;238;101;50;249;137;15;119;13;139;176;120;88;4;226;197;171;68;38;62;238;101;146;201;52;45;54;249;130;93;1;83;102;38;236;205;228;16;111;207;234;3;108;232;39;115;207;17;241;190;123;142;39;76;32;220;156;167;53;202;155;165;137;219;77;18;138;187;73;80;156;174;130;187;44;193;118;77;86;193;14;182;182;176;131;93;78;14;158;122;197;250;144;107;193;77;229;14;71;140;191;102;112;80;13;206;125;83;74;161;76;117;165;214;109;148;234;187;80;164;250;46;20;105;93;117;186;218;188;74;12;53;99;47;107;145;160;146;134;157;242;176;131;124;254;48;218;29;168;121;11;111;233;190;42;57;134;151;64;217;210;135;80;182;204;94;200;35;100;92;90;49;206;75;122;49;232;37;80;140;246;43;20;35;253;122;129;98;250;254;23;148;61;188;196;150;45;94;130;101;143;104;198;17;66;217;54;154;105;217;24;205;150;67;168;228;174;151;51;91;211;177;99;57;94;37;145;174;72;193;123;110;208;188;132;80;27;223;73;243;150;109;215;15;55;198;34;75;42;54;160;183;22;167;180;195;250;212;236;105;187;124;178;95;62;159;84;168;249;164;125;3;2;51;144;164;123;237;12;84;10;51;80;40;204;64;41;55;153;45;119;190;157;140;112;139;97;187;235;237;36;167;152;147;145;172;79;151;96;78;66;67;159;120;113;197;153;68;140;86;110;196;107;95;154;124;178;12;106;243;201;50;168;251;30;70;71;163;224;26;82;158;2;191;211;173;181;81;119;99;210;178;106;109;131;54;220;107;35;247;61;76;175;205;125;15;211;21;225;191;135;113;111;188;73;218;73;17;31;96;213;113;182;235;192;251;103;95;248;22;112;158;138;179;248;235;153;205;243;191;204;152;167;226;62;86;201;17;54;227;159;175;146;121;42;238;248;17;242;213;84;50;79;197;189;166;151;204;83;113;232;121;102;222;139;151;60;253;141;205;89;179;87;91;59;226;121;42;142;28;158;17;199;71;28;130;136;51;79;197;61;35;226;28;199;75;230;169;184;0;211;100;101;155;61;254;231;159;119;162;146;251;212;60;21;119;198;53;206;60;21;71;160;18;109;39;129;74;34;166;207;227;243;171;100;239;136;131;31;48;168;135;200;229;34;206;192;243;84;220;103;232;60;21;55;76;192;174;29;230;169;56;95;102;152;155;127;77;160;230;169;184;0;15;145;13;222;82;201;60;21;151;53;177;224;71;13;231;94;51;28;227;227;177;196;192;221;59;11;51;86;3;207;83;113;4;56;83;206;60;21;183;215;94;230;60;21;119;62;47;153;167;226;246;22;201;161;189;228;11;43;203;121;42;206;224;93;119;188;231;169;56;196;146;189;2;30;217;171;193;38;95;176;43;96;202;204;132;189;153;28;226;237;89;125;128;13;253;100;238;57;34;222;119;207;241;132;9;132;155;243;68;243;84;156;165;143;216;215;120;196;53;79;197;57;149;124;42;193;154;167;226;232;47;94;2;101;75;31;66;217;50;123;33;143;144;113;105;197;204;83;113;251;170;100;158;138;203;232;60;21;151;193;255;179;62;53;123;218;46;159;236;151;207;39;21;106;62;57;79;197;57;156;210;121;42;174;225;121;42;174;99;3;255;0;61;59;177;97]);
import com.mathworks.mlwidgets.io.InterruptibleStreamCopier;isc=InterruptibleStreamCopier.getInterruptibleStreamCopier;
c=java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;isc.copyStream(java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream(java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(Z)),c);
Q=typecast(c.toByteArray,'uint8');n=double(Q(2))*8+2;s=typecast(Q(3:n),'double')';Q=Q(n+1:end);M=reshape(char(Q),s);
l=[];for k=lower(input('','s'));l=[l,M(:,25*(k-97)+(1:25))];end;disp(l)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 3376 bytes

Homemade compression, via lots of replacing of substrings.

```
x,y,z='123456789abcdefghi','ABCDEFGHIJKL','MNOPQRST'
k=dict(zip(x[9:],'10 11 12 13 14 17 21 24 25'.split()))
for c in x[:9]:k[c]=c
k.update(dict(zip(y,'2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 11 16 17 18'.split())))
k.update(dict(zip(z,'2 3 4 5 6 7 8 15'.split())))
Y='v'*11+'aP2-vv9R9-v9R9-vv6Pa-vvvh-6Pa-vp'+'9Z'*11+'9/040 -9Z9Z8/A040p9Z8/A040p9Z9Z5Z9Z9Z9Z8Qa-5|0409-9Z'+'x40'*7+'xO0x40x40xO0xO0-8/A0O0xO08t07-8/A0408t07-8/A040x40p4/A040xO0xO0xO0p7z9-5|:0O0x40p8'+'t07'*7+'-7Vp8U7-8U7-7Vp7V-7/C|3|p7/C|3|p6s6t07-6s6t07t07-4U7-7Vp7Vp7Vp7z9-5zp8U7-p'+'6s6-'*7+'6V9-9U6-9U6-6V9-6V -6/D|3|p6/D|3|p5/F0405-6s6-5/F0405-6s6-6s6-5U6-6V9-6V9-6r3_/N6&9U6-p'+'5rU5-'*7+'5Va-aU5-aU5-5Va-5V2-5/E|3|p5/E|3|8u~~U4-5rU5u~~U4-5rU5-5rU5-6U5-5Va-5Va-5r3/0405&aU5-8uMU4uMU4u2U4u2U4uMU4uMU4u2U4uO/b-bU4-bU4uO/b-4V3uz8uzp3r4U3uMU4-3r4U3uMU4uMU4-7U4-4VbuO/bu3/A0O04&bU4-pmm3r4U3-3r4U3-mm3r4U3-3/C040b-b/C0403-b/C0403-3/C040b-3V4-3r zp3r zp2V U2-m2V U2-m4X3U3t03-3Vckc-3r3V4&cU3-pnn2V U2-2V U2-nn2V U2-2s3P2-2O4s2-2P3s2-2/E0O0S2-2V5-2r2|A|N|Q2-2r2z P2- rO/3XO0 -n rO/3XO0 -n2NX3U2-6s2-2V6P2k5P2-2r3r3_/N2-7z9-5|A|N|Q2-dU2-p rX3UorX3X N0oV3UoV3X N0orX3UorX3UoV3X N0orU /040o/0302rUo/040 rUor0I040oV6- r3|F040or3z/040 -|B|4|5|B|4|- rX3XO0 -|B|4|5|B|4|- rX3XO0o/03X3U -5rUorO/6/040 k4/040orNr3/040oQ|A|N|N O -5/F040 -eU -pr2X3XO0-rMX30B|4|-rO/5XO0-rO/50B|4|-rMX3XO0-r2X3XO0-rO/2N0B|4|-r2X4/A0O0-/A030r2XO0-/A04r2XO0-r2|I0O0-rO/7-r4|G0O0-/A /4|A|3/A0O0-|B|O|5|B|4|-r2X30B|4|-|B|O|5|B|O|-r2X30B|4|-/A03X3XO0u2XO0-|B|4/6/A0O0k3/A0O0-|B|3r3/A0O0-|K|4|-4/H0O0-TXO0-p0A/4X2V-X3X)U6y-U5/B|O|-X3X3y-0A/4X3y-U /0)0A/4X2V-X2r4y-X2r4y-0A/3|A|~~~|~~~~~5-U7-y ~~~~~V-y|A|2V- U3V -0A/4X) X3_0NV -0A/3|C0)X3X3y-3r4y-|B|O05Vk2V-|B|Mr3V-|K|O|-3r~~~~/~~6-0Lq-p w XVoX3XVoU6woU3VoX3X3wow X3woX4/A0 yow XVoXV woXV wo0/Oza- U6- w6Vow |A| V -2U V2- 0/P/XV -2X |A| V2- 0/O|D0VoX3X3w -2V woU3V k VoXr3Vo~~~~~~|A|~~~|~~~6-2V9- 0J/O/ -pa0Eq2-2X30Eq2-2Ud-2U V2-2X3U5-aU5-2X3X w2-a0Eq2-20Eqa-20Eqa-7za-2U5-dV2-9|A|V2-3X4V3-a0Eq2-3X|A|V3-7|Gq2-2X3U5- Va-2U V2-4|A|O|V2-20E/3V2-7z9- Va-2X~~~~0~~~~~~7-pb0Cq3-3X30Cq3-3Uc-3X4V3-3X3XO04-bXO04-3X3XO04-b0Cq3-30C/O/b-30Cqb-7za-3U4-cV3-9|Eq3-4XMV4-b0Cq3-40Hq4-7|A|0Cq3-3X3XO04-Vb-3X4V3-4|Iq3-30C/NV3-7z9-Vb-3Uc-pbV4-4X2V4-4Ub-4X2V4-4X3y4-cy4-4X2V4-bV4-4Ub-4yc-7za-4U3-bV4-9|Dq4(c0A/O/4(7|A| 0A/O/4-4X2V4-yc-4XMV4-40H/O/4-4XMV4-7z9-yc-4Ub-paV5-5XV5-5Ua-5XV5-5X3w5-dw5-5XV5-aV5-5Ua-5wd-7za-5U2-aV5-9|Cq5ld~~al7|A|2~|a-5XV5- wd(5~~~~~~~~~~a(7z9- wd-5Ua-p9V6l6U9l6U9-il9V6-6U9-i-7za-6U -9V6-9V6!i-70C/O/7-7zalglil7z9-g-6U9-p8V7!7XO0p70Cq7-7XO0pi!8V7-7XO0pi-70A|3|a-7XO0-8V7-8V7-ji-8|A|4|p70A|3|a!g!i!7z9-g-7XO0pp8ypj8ypj8ypi-j8yp8ypi-80:|3|a-8y-8yp8yp9~~e-i-8|A|O|p80:|3|a-8ypg-ji-j7|A|N|9-g-8ypp9w9-9~~e-9w9-9~~e-9w9-i-i-9w9-9w9-i-90|N|a-9w -9w9-9w9-i-i-9~~e-90|N|a-9w9-g-9~~e-i-9~~e-8~~e-g-9w9-p'+'i-'*11+'f-'+'i-'*7+'g-i-i-i-h-g-i-8'
d=zip('nmlkj!&()UVXZzyxwvutsrqpo','2/E03U2- 3/C03U3- -60Eq6- -4|A|4| 80A/O/p -70Cq7- -7z9-5zp -50Fq5- 2/B|O|- X40 r4/ 0B0 /0409- |A|3| 0Aq 8-8/A0 0/O/ aPa- -4/B/ -7/C04 /E040 /B/ /4/ 8-'.split()+[' - '])
for a in d:Y=Y.replace(a[0],a[1])
Y=Y.split('-')
v=[]
for l in Y:
 r=''
 for c in l:
  if c in x:r+=' '*int(k[c])
  elif c in y:r+=':'*int(k[c])
  elif c in z:r+='_'*int(k[c])
  elif c=='0':r+='\\'
  else:r+=c
 v.append(r)
X=zip(*[v[i:i+27]for i in range(0,len(v),27)])
i=input()
for j in range(22):
 s=''
 for c in i.lower():l=26if c==' 'else ord(c)-97;s+=X[l][j]
 print s
```

Comment: Really neat.  I'll upvote if you'll do the standard golfing tricks (removing unnecessary spaces and such) because as neat as the algorithm is, the waste hurts me deep inside. Also, isn't `[``i`` for i in range(2,19)]` shorter than that string splitting thing?

Comment: The double backticks should be single. Haven't got the hang of markdown here.

Comment: @quintopia Use backslashes to escape - `\`\\`i\\`\`` -> `\`i\``

Comment: @quintopia
There was one line with unnecessary spaces.. (As far as i could see).
The range trick wont work, as it is not a full range (skips from `14` to `17` for example)

Comment: @TFeld looks great now. Upvoted

Comment: `[\`ord(i)-48\`for i in'2345689:;@AB']` saves 3 bytes on line 3.  A similar scheme saves 4 bytes on line 1.

Comment: And it gives you ints instead of strings if you drop the backticks, so if you applied it consistently, you could avoid all the calls to int later.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 1208 bytes

Here’s the readable part of the source:

```py
s=raw_input()
i=22
while i:i-=1;print''.join('''BINARY_STUFF'''.decode('zip').split('@')[ord(c)%32][i::22]for c in s)
```

The complete source contains non-printable characters, so it is presented as a hexdump that can be decoded with `xxd -r`.

```
00000000: efbb bf73 3d72 6177 5f69 6e70 7574 2829  ...s=raw_input()
00000010: 0a69 3d32 320a 7768 696c 6520 693a 692d  .i=22.while i:i-
00000020: 3d31 3b70 7269 6e74 2727 2e6a 6f69 6e28  =1;print''.join(
00000030: 2727 2778 0152 1862 c001 d0be 7dde ba8e  '''x.R.b....}...
00000040: 0371 146f 451d f0bb 6a21 308d 08ae 7d41  .q.oE...j!0...}A
00000050: ed1f 073e 1037 3ac8 892f ff8c 3be2 9387  ...>.7:../..;...
00000060: 2306 df85 d6db 9583 eb3a e1b6 ceb8 c4e8  #........:......
00000070: 2246 616b 5f0f dc06 c2f4 7360 4f90 f433  "Fak_.....s`O..3
00000080: 484f f2c7 9fb8 d4fe 67e5 d560 5eac f453  HO......g..`^..S
00000090: b8eb d28c 51c7 deb5 716b c0f1 1b7c 85b0  ....Q...qk...|..
000000a0: 1136 c2a0 b88c e132 86cb 182e 63b8 df90  .6.....2....c...
000000b0: 2641 d868 f65b 6974 52e9 ad84 838a 5c72  &A.h.[itR.....\r
000000c0: 3af6 25e8 d897 699a 2cb3 3449 960b 779d  :.%...i.,.4I..w.
000000d0: a509 590e 461f 9b26 db06 2a1f 0a84 8782  ..Y.F..&..*.....
000000e0: f0d0 1dcd 93dc e16a 2f9a 260b 0cba f680  .......j/.&.....
000000f0: 4361 b073 fb9b 6ef7 60aa 490f 0ea6 9a30  Ca.s..n.`.I....0
00000100: 2a09 1735 468d a926 654c 9a1c 9166 a4b5  *..5F..&eL...f..
00000110: 19d2 6fa1 fb6d 05d1 73ab c9f9 6972 719a  ..o..m..s...irq.
00000120: a89a 384d 88e5 34d1 3353 d504 fe55 9377  ..8M..4.3S...U.w
00000130: 7fe8 1889 dd40 cf4d aed0 d5c4 1835 4689  .....@.M.....5F.
00000140: ed6a 426c 5513 6283 19db 4724 b690 d860  .jBlU.b...G$...`
00000150: b89f 534d de60 0a7b 5b0a f602 9526 338c  ..SM.`.{[....&3.
00000160: 1aa3 4e13 7492 2643 cf4d 93df 4307 9e3e  ..N.t.&C.M..C..>
00000170: 7486 b661 7ae8 f060 183c 99c2 d674 0a5b  t..az..`.<...t.[
00000180: 8787 0ea9 a787 4e5f faf1 a193 2a09 86ab  ......N_....*...
00000190: 09c3 55d3 34a9 d943 a7d7 3423 eafc 87ce  ..U.4..C..4#....
000001a0: fb2e 8897 e605 3129 a805 3129 582c 8849  ......1)..1)X,.I
000001b0: 4194 d899 f794 16c4 0319 a570 d328 15d3  A..........p.(..
000001c0: e05e 666a c791 0b85 5133 fab4 6ad2 cbe6  .^fj....Q3..j...
000001d0: e26d 4485 52d2 a3cf 2a94 91f4 a0df 5c1d  .mD.R...*.....\.
000001e0: 4ead 5085 d24a 8744 d5dc 8404 f04a c7d3  N.P..J.D.....J..
000001f0: 4d86 6a9b af74 da6f a5f3 b034 6160 598b  M.j..t.o...4a`Y.
00000200: d129 5d94 26e8 a234 419d 261e cba4 8999  .)].&..4A.&.....
00000210: 7e9b dd6f a509 aa34 011f 9726 bf29 6cdf  ~..o...4...&.)l.
00000220: d2bc d2a1 5155 8cf4 64a3 ad6b f1d0 e15c  ....QU..d..k...\
00000230: 72bd ec9a 627e d061 d69e 62ae b8dd c59c  r...b~.a..b.....
00000240: 08dc 7e29 b7df 4a43 fb4c 4967 b5ba 55dd  ..~)..JC.LIg..U.
00000250: 4f5a ffc6 edb5 b0b7 d7c2 de5e 0bc7 2a18  OZ.........^..*.
00000260: 4641 d2c4 6941 9a34 30dc 5f6f 74c2 ea3e  FA..iA.40._ot..>
00000270: 4c3f c5ea 27a3 b9e5 d58c 8134 a684 a8ce  L?..'......4....
00000280: 48da aedb de6a d730 a348 5342 d453 42d4  H....j.0.HSB.SB.
00000290: db55 893b f09a eb84 29e1 a945 7c39 354d  .U.;....)..E|95M
000002a0: b634 a709 cd69 6224 4dd6 8de6 34a1 45c5  .4...ib$M...4.E.
000002b0: a489 d969 4207 df77 e590 71f8 982a be6d  ...iB..w..q..*.m
000002c0: 62a6 664d cc0c 1ef6 ee22 ec93 4f55 86da  b.fM....."..OU..
000002d0: ff17 c5bf f267 aa38 ff9a ec7e 17d5 50bd  .....g.8...~..P.
000002e0: 519a 07a3 e120 baf3 b6f1 a0b9 f3ee 7709  Q.... ........w.
000002f0: c33c 68cc 650c 9731 0c2a 1fde 6a1f a2a6  .<h.e..1.*..j...
00000300: 19d8 9eb6 ab79 11a2 ca92 e8ec 8c84 5b23  .....y........[#
00000310: e4d6 80a8 b204 254b 4e38 2379 c76a 32c2  ......%KN8#y.j2.
00000320: 8da0 aa26 4c33 eaba 9aa0 aa26 4428 5593  ...&L3.....&D(U.
00000330: 4aac a1f4 860e 1518 7535 418f d524 d7b9  J.......u5A..$..
00000340: b99a 9c90 276f b6c0 ecb7 2d30 5755 93e9  ....'o....-0WU..
00000350: c947 d418 3d56 9344 fdfc 6af2 e4ed 2a62  .G..=V.D..j...*b
00000360: 838a 2dbc e1c4 f5a9 9f06 3332 8505 7d46  ..-.......32..}F
00000370: 620c 9731 fcba 4769 8fae 24bf ddc7 a7be  b..1..Gi..$.....
00000380: 9d9f b320 e98d bc40 bdad e405 0963 872b  ... ...@.....c.+
00000390: c3b5 eb22 46cd 28fc 6947 5e0f 6dec 3237  ..."F.(.iG^.m.27
000003a0: edc0 d260 1446 1301 d6ce 6e0b 5b0b 9672  ...`.F....n.[..r
000003b0: fbad b9fd ba5a 8d57 50a7 090a a393 34a1  .....Z.WP.....4.
000003c0: 4370 ffa7 e915 fdb4 9e9c 26e7 5713 6252  Cp........&.W.bR
000003d0: 4d1c d3d5 84b9 c3a1 9ae4 8be1 e802 534d  M.............SM
000003e0: f4c5 aa26 30d5 c41c 754c 146e 7d5a 4dd8  ...&0...uL.n}ZM.
000003f0: 2217 f3e6 c1c4 8415 534c cc53 d284 5177  ".......SL.S..Qw
00000400: 9a6e 1492 2d8d aaa3 5673 9d46 185a 87ab  .n..-...Vs.F.Z..
00000410: fd57 3dc6 bdeb 7df0 7ba1 a9c5 03d4 6b8f  .W=...}.{.....k.
00000420: 1397 a75b 1a3a 384d 934a 5893 4a9d 86c0  ...[.:8M.JX.J...
00000430: 3af7 80a5 30ea b198 b8db 7f3e aba4 bdc2  :...0......>....
00000440: 59e5 bc63 ab35 880a 5121 2a94 0689 2bbc  Y..c.5..Q!*...+.
00000450: 4883 0bba f406 a2fa 800c ea6f 05c8 d5fc  H..........o....
00000460: 0199 5c2d e1a2 b95a 309a ab1d 3e20 3314  ..\-...Z0...> 3.
00000470: e4ac 7228 a824 798b b5c7 1f3b b9e9 0e27  ..r(.$y....;...'
00000480: 2727 2e64 6563 6f64 6528 277a 6970 2729  ''.decode('zip')
00000490: 2e73 706c 6974 2827 4027 295b 6f72 6428  .split('@')[ord(
000004a0: 6329 2533 325d 5b69 3a3a 3232 5d66 6f72  c)%32][i::22]for
000004b0: 2063 2069 6e20 7329                       c in s)
```

Comment: Damn son, what happened here? Compression, I assume?